local time of calendar event
When I use a script like
 var now = new Date(),
      then = new Date();

  // _interval is passed to cal.getEvents as nr of seconds

  then.setSeconds(now.getSeconds() + _interval);
  Logger.log('then = ' + then);

  // get all calendar events between 'now' and 'then'
  // create an empty response object
  
  var items = cal.getEvents(now, then),
      length = items.length,
      response = {};    
  
  // if cal.getEvents returns any events (length > 0)
  // get the title and the date of the event and save this to the output array

  if (length)
  {
    arr = [];
    itemCount = 0;

    for(var item of items)
    {
      var obj = {TYPE: item.getTitle(), DATE: item.getAllDayStartDate()}
      arr.push(obj);
      if(++itemCount >= 10) {
        break;
      }

    }

'now' is the point in time when the script is called, 'then' is that point in time + an interval, expressed in seconds. That works. The problem I have is this:
When a calendar event is an all-day event the script always returns the day before the event at a time 23:00:00.000Z. My time zone in Google calendar is set to GMT + 1, but the  function item.getAllDayStartDate() seems to ignore the setting. Of course I can add the time offset to the returned result in the application which receives the response from the script, but I'd rather see the script returning the correct date.
How can I fix that?

Which scripting language is that?!

Resolved in a strange way. I've been experimenting a bit and when I changed the statement

var obj = {TYPE: item.getTitle(), DATE: item.getAllDayStartDate()}

to this:

var obj = {TYPE: item.getTitle(), DATE: (item.getStartTime() + (3 *
HOUR))}

I didn't get the (wrong) start time + 3 hours, which would put the event at the correct date. Instead I now get the correct date and time, including the deviation from UTC time as 'GMT+0100'. This is what I originally wanted.
Maybe adding an amount of time to the result of item.getStartTime() implicitly converts the result to local time???
